# Capistrano not getting past 'on roles(:app)'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm currently trying to write a custom rake task which looks like this:

```
namespace :import do
  desc 'Import excel file'
  task :excel, :filepath do |task, args|
    on roles(:app) do
      file_path = args[:filepath]
      file_name = file_path.split('/').last
      home_path = "/var/www/my_app/current/"
      server_path = home_path+file_name
      upload!(file_path, "#{server_path}")
      run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rake 'excel:import[#{server_path}]' RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
    end
  end
end
```

Now, when I type in `cap production import:excel[/path/to/file.txt]` nothing happens. I've found out that it does not go into the `on roles(:app) do` block but skips it. Removing that line throws an `undefined method upload!` error.

Does anyone know why it's skipped? Or can I use `upload!` without the `on roles` block?

*UPDATE:*

```
role :app, %w{master@1.2.3.4}
role :web, %w{master@1.2.3.4}
role :db,  %w{master@1.2.3.4}
server '1.2.3.4', user: 'master', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value
```

Comment: You may be chasing a red herring here.  I copied your code and ran locally on a project and it seems to output the value I passed into the argument without issue.


namespace :import do
  desc 'Import excel file'
  task :excel, :filepath do |task, args|
    on roles(:app) do
      puts args[:filepath]
    end
  end
end

➜ : be cap staging import:excel[asdasd]
asdasd


**Stupid formatting not working**

Comment: So you removed everything and added `puts args[:filepath]` and it all worked? Well, that's good to know but makes my problem even worse.

Comment: Yes, I got output.  I suspect you may have other issues, like not having an app server defined in your deploy file for your environment?

Comment: I've updated my question, to me it seems all right?

Comment: I don't think you need the declaration of the first 3 lines.  I have never seen nor have I had the need to do this.You should be applying the roles to the server line on the 4th line.

Answer (score 0):

Try and run your task with --trace to get more information about what's happening, adding some `puts` statements will also help.

Comment: I did, `roles(:app)` returns an empty Array but that doesn't really help me. Are the roles not set?

Comment: If it's empty then you probably don't have the roles set, or they are not being picked up. Do you have something like: `server 'test.com', user: 'usr', roles: %w{web app db}
` in your config/deploy/production.rb?

Answer (score 0):

```
server 'x.x.x.x', user: 'username', roles: %w(web app jobs db rollbar whenever)

set :user, 'username'
set :branch, ENV.fetch('BRANCH', 'master')
set :rails_env, 'qa'
set :server_name, 'qa'

set :nginx_server_name, '_'
set :nginx_default_server, false
set :deploy_to, "/home/rails/#{fetch(:application)}-#{fetch(:server_name)}"
```

This is a sample of the striped down deploy file we use.  I don't know what the declaration you have on the top 3 lines are for, I have never seen that.  Normally you just define the roles within the line with the server declaration.

Comment: Never seen it? It's actually in the template stage file of capsitrano: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/templates/stage.rb.erb

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason it works now, I just didn't touch the code for a few days and now it works. ‍♂️